# Spring Cloud Data Flow Server for Cloudfoundry - external datasource

Tags: cloud-foundry, spring-cloud-dataflow

Using:  Pivotal Cloudfoundry v2.x, Spring Cloud Data Flow Server v1.6.2.RELEASE, SQL Server 2016.

The server datasource configuration does not appear to successfully create a datasource if it is not a service bound to the application within PCF.

The SQL Server database is not a service provisioned within our PCF marketplace.  I've rebuilt the server application and added the SQL Server jdbc driver jar to the classpath.  I also included the datasource configuration:

```
---
applications: 
- path: spring-cloud-dataflow-server-cloudfoundry-1.6.2.RELEASE.jar
  name: dataflow-server
  host: dataflow-server
  memory: 4096M
  disk_quota: 2048M
  no-route: false
  no-hostname: false
  health-check-type: 'port' 
  buildpack: java_buildpack_offline
  env: 
    JAVA_OPTS: -Dhttp.keepAlive=false
    JBP_CONFIG_CONTAINER_CERTIFICATE_TRUST_STORE: '{enabled: true}' 
    SPRING_CLOUD_DEPLOYER_CLOUDFOUNDRY_SPACE: channing
    SPRING_CLOUD_DEPLOYER_CLOUDFOUNDRY_STREAM_APP_NAME_PREFIX: channing
    SPRING_CLOUD_DEPLOYER_CLOUDFOUNDRY_URL: https://api.pcf.com
    SPRING_CLOUD_DEPLOYER_CLOUDFOUNDRY_DOMAIN: pcf.com
    SPRING_APPLICATION_NAME: dataflow-server
    SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:sqlserver://nonpcf.sqlserver.com\\DBINSTANCE:1713;databaseName=SCDF_DEV 
    SPRING_DATASOURCE_DRIVER_CLASS_NAME: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
    SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: username
    SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: password
  services: 
    - config-server
    - rabbit
  security: 
    basic: 
      enabled: true
      realm: Spring Cloud Data Flow
  spring: 
    cloud: 
      dataflow: 
        features: 
          analytics-enabled: false
```

The error occurs during application startup, stating an unresolved dependency where there is no unique instance of javax.sql.DataSource available for injection.

Here is some stacktrace:

```
2018-10-23T09:39:14.365-06:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] Caused by: org.springframework.cloud.CloudException: No unique service matching interface javax.sql.DataSource found. Expected 1, found 0
2018-10-23T09:39:14.365-06:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.cloud.Cloud.getSingletonServiceConnector(Cloud.java:197) ~[spring-cloud-connectors-core-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
2018-10-23T09:39:14.365-06:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.cloud.config.java.CloudServiceConnectionFactory.dataSource(CloudServiceConnectionFactory.java:56) ~[spring-cloud-spring-service-connector-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
2018-10-23T09:39:14.365-06:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.server.cloudfoundry.config.DataSourceCloudConfig.scdfCloudDataSource(DataSourceCloudConfig.java:47) ~[spring-cloud-dataflow-server-cloudfoundry-autoconfig-1.6.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.6.2.RELEASE]
```

Is this on purpose?  How can we bind the PCF SCDF server with a datasource that is not resident within the foundation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Cloud Data Flow's CF-server builds upon an opinion of relying on Spring Cloud Connector for `datasource` and [connection-pool customization](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-cloudfoundry/blob/master/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-cloudfoundry-autoconfig/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/dataflow/server/cloudfoundry/config/DataSourceCloudConfig.java).

Since we do this intentionally to take advantage of the automation provided by the library, we don't have a direct ability to turn it off in SCDF itself.

However, there's an option to turn-off Spring Cloud Connector from interfering entirely, and that option is available as a Spring Boot property (i.e., `spring.cloud=false`), which also applies to SCDF, too.

With this property set at the CF-server, you'd be able to create a connection pool using the `SPRING_DATASOURCE_*` properties like how it is defined in the `manifest.yml` above.

**UPDATE**

*Background*: The declarative `datasource` overrides and Spring Cloud Connector (in the classpath) are mutually exclusive and they cannot work together in any capacity.

Hence, it is advised to stick to a single model when customizing the CF-server. The easiest solution in this case, of course, is to disable connector altogether.